# Android how to turn on do not disturb (dnd) programmatically

Tags: android

How do I turn on/off 'do not disturb' (dnd) programmatically in Android?  Is was hoping this would give me something but it doesn't:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.DO_NOT_DISTURB, 1);
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
```

It requires:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

Which as far as I can tell does not pop up a request dialog when doing requestPermissions(). It has to be granted through the settings menu Settings -> Sound & Notifcation -> Do Not Disturb Access.

This is on SDK 23 Marshmallow.

Comment: `setInterruptionFilter` is for Lollipop notification priority filter. Use `setNotificationPolicy` instead.

Comment: Will it also hide heads-up notifications? Or just the sound&vibration? How would you block them on Lollipop and below?

Comment: @JasonHu both methods require Android API 23 and above, which is Android M .

Comment: This requires me to pop up a notification?

Comment: @androiddeveloper it seems like it sadly does not hide heads-up notifications

Comment: with setNotificationPolicy you can set the Do Not Disturb "Allow Interruptions" policies like NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_CATEGORY_ALARM ( allow alarm )

with setInterruptionFilter you set the actual Don Not Disturb on or off where :

NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY = set DND on with the setNotificationPolicy settings

NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE = set DND on for every interuption

NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL = set DND off

Answer (score 38):

Just improving the answer from Jordan Parsons.
To set the priority you need a permission that can only be obtained by asking the user opening an Activity.
An activity will be prompted asking if you want to enable the permission for Do Not Disturb to you application.

This Activity can be opened this way:

```
 NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 // Check if the notification policy access has been granted for the app.
 if (!mNotificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
     startActivity(intent);
 }
```

After granting this permission, this setting can be changed.

Comment: This seems to cause LG phones crash (in process com.android.settings). Anybody have any idea how to workaround?

Comment: I have a LG Nexus 5x running android 7.1.1 and this works. Thanks!

Comment: LG Nexus 5x is LG only by hardware. It has pure Android so it works. Problem is on LG G4 and on LG Flex 2 with Android 6.0.1 (at least, I don't own neither of those phones).

Comment: BTW: We are discussing this issue on LG Developer Forums: http://mobile.developer.lge.com/support/forums/general/?pageMode=Detail&tID=10000362 

Please join discussion if you struggle from this issue.

Comment: Good answer.  But you probably should have edited Jordan's answer rather than creating another one.

Comment: my app does not show in the list of apps for for me to toggle the settings

Answer (score 7):

For those struggling with LG G4, there is a workaround.

LG didn't setup the settings option to grant

```
permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY
```

Therefore it crashes when it receives

```
ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS
```

However, LG did setup the option to grant

```
permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE
```

And once this permission is granted, so is

```
permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY
```

(at least on LG G4). This option is under Settings->General->Security->Notification access. For the user to be able to grant this permission, your app needs to request for it. This is done by declaring your service, assuming you have one for your app, as follows in the manifest:

```
<service android:name="myService"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Hi, I need to request this permission from an Activity. How can I do that?

Comment: Then should we start the activity with intent ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS  from myService ? Can you please explain little more.