# Overriding notifications in Android

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to override notifications that are outside the scope of the app.  I have read on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html on how to create and manage notifications but I'm looking to silence all (even outside the scope) notifications when an app is running.  Can it be done?(dun dun duuunnnnnnnn!)

Comment: I highly doubt you can modify the way other apps work

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using a [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) to control notifications if that's what you want, but I think you really want to temporarily [silence a phone's notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862753/android-how-to-turn-on-do-not-disturb-dnd-programmatically) and not dismiss them. That will probably not give users a good experience though.

Comment: You cannot modify notifications of another app in any way.

Comment: You wouldn't modify them, but you could dismiss them or turn on Do Not Disturb mode so users don't see the notification.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#cancelAllNotifications()