# android: how to turn on Do not disturb mode programmatically on lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I've already checked 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862753/android-how-to-turn-on-do-not-disturb-dnd-programmatically) where I found bellow solution.

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
```

But it works for "above lollipop" versions. Can anybody please tell me how I'll be able to control Do not disturb setting such as toggle them,  switch between alarm only , Priority only , total silent.

Comment: did you get any solution for this?