# Mute Button not working

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm trying to add a mute button to my android project app just learning the basics here's what I did. I created a Button (this is just for now in the future I will try to use Switch) id set as `android:id="@+id/muteBtn"` and declared the varaibles in java `Button muteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.muteBtn) ;`
and when its click it must put the mode to silent mode I added a `user-permission` because its giving me an error `Not allowed to change Do Not Disturb state`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

and here's the button click listener

```
 muteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                    && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.Settings
                                .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else {
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) Settings.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
            }
        }
    });
```

this method is not working any suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**

i just noticed this code works but the `ringer` volume volume goes down instead of `media`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862753/android-how-to-turn-on-do-not-disturb-dnd-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:  I am assuming you want to put down the volume of music and not put the phone on silent mode... Please correct me if i am wrong..

```
    if (!isMute) {
        AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        currentVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        isMute = true;
        mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
        imageButtonMute.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.mute_off));
     } else {

 imageButtonMute.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.mute));
      AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) 
      activity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
     isMute = false;                       
     mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, currentVolume, 0);
    }
```

Comment: why is it giving me the same error `Non-static method setMode(int) cannot be referenced from a static content` im inside `onCreate` method

Comment: i havnt used the setMode Method, can you post the exact line on which it is giving that error ?

Comment: ` AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);` I change the word activity here and replace my `Settings` java class and then the `getSystemService` becomes underlined with red color and says the error i mentioned

Comment: change it to Settings.this

Comment: AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) Settings.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

Comment: or try it without that.
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); –

Comment: thanks for the help! maybe I'm a bit confused and dig up for more and this just solved my problem. `setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

public void onClick(View v) {

```
  switch (v.getId()) {
  case R.id.wmute:
    AudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    AudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
     break;
  default:
     break;
  }
```

}
          }

```
   }
```

Comment: already tried it and it doesn't work it also gives an error `Non-static method setMode(int) cannot be referenced from a static content`

Comment: follow this lonk:  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html