# Opening Do Not Disturb preferences in Oreo

Tags: android, android-intent, android-preferences, android-8.1-oreo

I'm having troubles opening system [DND preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9SSR.jpg) from my App so that user can create or edit [Automatic Time rule](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-adjust-do-not-disturb-settings-android-o).

**Current situation**

Our app already has a similar feature which disables App-notification LED, sound and vibration for some specific time period (for example between 10pm-8am) and is applied app-wide. As of Android Oreo, our feature doesn't work anymore because of Notification Channels. The only solution is, as far as I understand, to create in System preferences [Automatic Time rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50nZ0.jpg) which is then applied system-wide.

**What I want to do?**

Just to redirect Oreo user from my app to System preferences ie. *Do Not Disturb preferences* in order to add or edit Time rule.

**The problem**

There is no specific `Intent` which opens *Do Not Disturb preferences*. The closest one I could find was [`Settings.ACTION_ZEN_MODE_PRIORITY_SETTINGS`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-mr1-release/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#1124) which leads me to [this Preference screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfm5e.jpg). I also found [action which I exactly need](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-mr1-release/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#1167), but as you can see, it is hidden by annotation.

Does this mean there is no way to open this Preference screen and I should use another approach?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862753/android-how-to-turn-on-do-not-disturb-dnd-programmatically) might help.

Comment: I tried, but this intent opens [DND access](https://imgur.com/a/cDsAbbi). Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this question for a long time, now I finally found the solution that works for me:

**Java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$ZenModeSettingsActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

**Kotlin**

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.component = ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings\$ZenModeSettingsActivity")
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [`AndroidManifest.xml` for the *Settings* app](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-5.0.0_r1.0.1:packages/apps/Settings/AndroidManifest.xml;l=599) you can see that there is an `Activity` `Settings$ZenModeSettingsActivity` (as mentioned by @cyb3rko in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63713587/467650) already from Android 5.0.

To send the user to the "Do not disturb" screen you can use the action `android.settings.ZEN_MODE_SETTINGS` like this:

```
try {
    startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ZEN_MODE_SETTINGS"));
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO: Handle activity not found
}
```

I would expect the intent filter to be even more stable than the class name.