# Auto silent android N and later

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-7.0-nougat, silent-notification

i am building an android app where i need to put the user's phone on silent mode. i am using different methods and it is working nicely up to android M(Level 23). 
Now as all of we know that android has updated the policy of auto silent mode in android N and later and needs special permission of Do Not Disturb Access to put phone on silent mode. I also did the same for android N and later OS releases. But it is not still working on android N and Later. When i a doing all this it doesn't give me any error but still it is not working. I am attaching the code snippets below have a look and try to figure out the issue. Thanks buddies.

**Code Snippet where i am giving Do Not Disturb Access to App**

```
public void onRingerPermissionsClicked(View view) {
    Intent intent = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

[image: Do Not Disturb Access Screenshot]

**Method to put phone on silent**

```
setRingerMode(context, AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

**Method setRingerMode()**

```
private void setRingerMode(Context context, int mode) {
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Check for DND permissions for API 24+
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24 ||
            (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24 && !nm.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted())) {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setRingerMode(mode);
    }
}
```

Comment: probably, duplicate for this -> (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862753/android-how-to-turn-on-do-not-disturb-dnd-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way only works on API<23, after API 23 you need to use notification manager to put mobile phone on "DND mode", here's how you can do it.

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
```

Have you added the permission for notification policy in Manifest file?? if not, then add this,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

you need to open separate Dialog for getting DND mode permission, which you can do by following,

// Check if the notification policy access has been granted for the app.

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (!mNotificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
     startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Comment: Yes i have added permission also

Comment: i have implemented the same and still facing the same problem on android 7 and later.

Comment: @RaQib If this Didn't work for you, you can try this --> https://android--examples.blogspot.in/2017/08/android-turn-on-off-do-not-disturb-mode.html

Comment: Yes it worked . There was problem in of condition. Now it  is working like charm. Thanks dear for your support!

Comment: welcome buddy, if you find answer helpful then accept the answer to help others find the correct answer.

Comment: I did this, I have the permission granted on the app but it still doesn't change the ringer mode. I'm testing on Android 9 (API level 28), what could be wrong?

Comment: @JayDangar when I'm inside of the app, it works, but when the app is the background it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Nevermind, I was sending the push notifications from Firebase Cloud Console, so the app was not executing the desired code.

Comment: @DavidCorral Great.

Comment: @JayDangar I am using the INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE but my phone keeps vibrating. Is there any way you know of so I can turn off vibration as well

Comment: @Gautam, so it's in dnd mode but vibrates?

Comment: @JayDangar from the statusbar icon, I can verify it goes into silent mode not DND