# React Native Android How to Turn On DND Mode?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I need to turn on the Do Not Disturb mode on Android, in my React Native App.

It does not need to be Cross Platform, just needs to work on Android.

I found [Android how to turn on do not disturb (dnd) programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862753/android-how-to-turn-on-do-not-disturb-dnd-programmatically) but since, I don't know Native Development I can't get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-settings-list

Comment: It's just a display component, I want it to enable the DND mode

Comment: @AswinMohan Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: 2022, as of today, still not possible using react native... :(